# MongoDB aggregating multiple arrays of objects based on shared key

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm writing a query to calculate multiple metrics for each user in my DB.

I've calculated all of the metrics, and have a structure like this

```
{  
  "metric1": [{"user_id": 1, "val": 13},{"user_id": 2, "val": 100}],
  "metric2": [{"user_id": 2, "val": 29},{"user_id": 1, "val": 123}],
  "metric3": [{"user_id": 1, "val": 46},{"user_id": 2, "val": 111]
}
```

I'm trying to convert the above into this structure

```
{ 
  "user_id": [1,2],
  "metric1": [13, 100],
  "metric2": [29,123],
  "metric3": [46,111]
}
```

So that I can display a table showing each user and the three metrics (one metric per column, and one user per row).

Comment: Please share collection

Comment: It looks like your input documents are _not_ of document or JSON format. You will need a properly formatted input document(s) to process as a MongoDB query.

Answer (score 1):

considering that your data is what you've said:

```
{
  "metric1": [
    {"id1": 1}, {"id2": 2}
  ],
    "metric2": [
    {"id2": 22}, {"id1": 11}
  ],
    "metric3": [
    {"id2": 222}, {"id1": 111}
  ]
}
```

all you've to do is using `$unwind` to be able to break the array and then `$objectToArray` to have access to keys

```
db.blah.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$metric1' },
  { $unwind: '$metric2' },
  { $unwind: '$metric3' },
  { $project: {'metric1': { $objectToArray: '$metric1' }, 'metric2': { $objectToArray: '$metric2' }, 'metric3': { $objectToArray: '$metric3' }} },
  { $sort: { 'metric1.k' : -1} },
  { $sort: { 'metric2.k' : -1} },
  { $sort: { 'metric3.k' : -1} },
  { $unwind: '$metric1' },
  { $unwind: '$metric2' },
  { $unwind: '$metric3' },
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    user_id: { $addToSet: '$metric1.k' },
    metric1: { $addToSet: '$metric1.v' },
    metric2: { $addToSet: '$metric2.v' },
    metric3: { $addToSet: '$metric3.v' },
  } },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } }
]).pretty()
```

which results

```
{
    "user_id" : [
        "id1",
        "id2"
    ],
    "metric1" : [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "metric2" : [
        11,
        22
    ],
    "metric3" : [
        111,
        222
    ]
}
```

Comment: I didn't word my question well, my bad. I updated the question to be more concise. Your solution makes sense, now I'm just trying to convert my data into the format you began with.